# Thin wrapper library to make the Numpy array API more intuitive and pythonic

Tags: open-source, library

A while ago, I stumbled across a talk in an archive of a developer conference introducing a thin wrapper around the [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) library that makes it more intuitive and "pythonic", especially when it comes to array operations involving multiple dimensions, appending/concatenating and `axis` arguments to various functions.

Unfortunately, I cannot remember the name of the library or the conference - it may have been FOSDEM, but I was unable to find it via a search there or on the internet.

I have seen [JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/) which does have slightly different/better indexing semantics than plain Numpy but is too rich/heavy for my needs.